# SQL Max Value of Column to choose which row is selected

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2014

I'm having a problem with selecting a single row when there are multiple entries for one "callid"

In this case there are two rows being selected:

```
Assignee           maxTime
Jim Smith         11:31:05
James Smith       17:50:16
```

I want to only select a single row that has the greatest time.

Output I want:

```
 Assignee          maxTime
 James Smith      17:50:16
```

This is my code:

```
select Assignee, MAX(TimeResolv) as maxTime 
from heat8..asgnmnt 
where callid ='00539265' 
    and GroupName like '%cs%' 
Group by Assignee
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can do TOP 1 and Order by maxTime desc

Comment: Show sample table data as well. (The one giving the specified result.)

Comment: This worked- thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TOP` :

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM heat8..asgnmntt t
ORDER BY t.timeResolv DESC
```

Or less efficient with `NOT EXISTS()`:

```
SELECT * FROM heat8..asgnmntt t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM heat8..asgnmnt s
                 WHERE s.timeResolv > t.timeResolv)
```

Or with window function `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SELECT s.Assignee, s.TimeResolv
FROM (
    SELECT t.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.timeResolv) as rnk
    FROM heat8..asgnmntt t) s
WHERE s.rnk = 1
```

`ROW_NUMBER()` is also good to do it with one query for results per group.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery. Your subquery will look exactly like your current query, but you will need to select top 1 from it.

```
select TOP 1 Assignee, (TimeResolv) as maxTime
FROM (
     select Assignee, MAX(TimeResolv) as maxTime 
     from heat8..asgnmnt 
     where callid ='00539265' 
     and GroupName like '%cs%' 
     Group by Assignee
)
ORDER BY TimeResolv DESC
```

EDIT: no need for subquery, but if you want to use the same code you did above for easy readability or it just makes sense to you. You can continue to use it with this method.

Comment: No need for sub query

Comment: I updated the answer. No need for subquery but sometimes its nice for readability if you are just beginning with SQL.